# Не работает функция считывания структуры из файла

Tags: c++, c, файлы

Не работает функция считывания структуры из файла (fromfile()).
И второе: неоходимо по номеру введенному номеру id изменить оценки студента, но работает только с введенным последним id, в чем могут быть ошибки?

```
    struct fig 
{
    char surn[30];
    int mark[100];
    int modulcount;         
    int id; 
};
void fCloseFile(FILE *file) 
{
    fclose(file);
}
void push(fig *&stud)
{

    cout<<"Введите id: "<<endl;
    cin>>stud->id;
    cout<<"Введите фамилию :"<<endl;
    cin>>stud->surn;    
    cout<<"Введите кол-во модулей: "<<endl;
    cin>>stud->modulcount;
    cout<<"Введите оценки: "<<endl;
    for(int j=0; j<stud->modulcount; j++)
    {
        cin>>stud->mark[j];     
    }       
}
void infile(FILE* file, fig *stud)
{
    push(stud);
    int sum = 0;
    cout << "id: " << stud->id << endl;
    cout << "Фамилия: " << stud->surn << endl;
    cout << "Кол-во модулей : " << stud->modulcount << endl;
    cout << "Оценки : " << endl;
    for(int j=0; j<stud->modulcount; j++)
    {
        cout<<stud->mark[j]<<" ";
        sum+=stud->mark[j];
    }
    if (sum>=60)
        cout<<"Зачет "<<endl;
    else cout<<"Незачет "<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    fwrite(stud, sizeof(file), 1, file);
    cout << "Данные в файл записаны \n";
    fCloseFile(file);
}

void fromfile(char *filename)
{
    fig stud;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename,"rb");
    fread(&stud, sizeof(fig), 1, file);
    cout << "Данные из файла: "<<endl;
    cout << "id: " << stud.id << endl;
    cout << "Фамилия: " << stud.surn << endl;
    cout << "Кол-во модулей : " << stud.modulcount << endl;
    for(int j=0; j<stud.modulcount; j++)
    {
        cout<<stud.mark[j]<<" ";
    }
    fCloseFile(file);
    return;
}
FILE* fOpenFile(char *filename) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename,"a+b");
    return file;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251); 
    fig *student = new fig;
    char *fName = "myfile.txt";
    FILE *file = fOpenFile(fName);
    cout<<"Введите кол-во студентов: "<<endl;
    int num;
    int vibor;
    int p=0;
    int change;
    int newmark[100];
    cin>>num;
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        infile(file,student);
    }   
    fromfile(fName);
    cout<<"Редактировать оценки студента? 1-да, 0-нет "<<endl;
    cin>>vibor;
    if (vibor==0)
        cout<<"Завершение программы... "<<endl;
    else 
    {
        cout<<"Ввод id: "<<endl;
        cin>>change;

        for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            if (student->id==change)
            {
        cout<<"Введите оценки: "<<endl;
        for(int j=0; j<student->modulcount; j++)
        {       
            cin>>newmark[j];
            student->mark[j]=newmark[j];

        }       
        break;
            }
        }
        cout<<"Завершение программы... "<<endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему вы пишете один размер (размер указателя)

```
fwrite(stud, sizeof(file), 1, file);
```

а читаете другой?

```
fread(&stud, sizeof(fig), 1, file);
```

Comment: Я хотел сделать так, чтобы в обеих функциях были не указатели, а сам объект структуры, но в fread нельзя убрать указатель

Comment: Блин... Ладно, разжуем еще... `fwrite(stud, sizeof(file), 1, file);` - что тут должно быть внутри `size()`?

Comment: fig? пробовал, ничего не поменялось

Comment: А вы, заметим, не написали ни слова о том, что значит "не работает" :) Так что "не поменялось" - ничуть не более информативно :)

Comment: я так второй день что-то меняю :) все работает, но в то же время не работает, вот такой парадокс. а не подскажете, что можно сделать во второй части моего вопроса? у меня изменения вносятся только в последнюю структуру, остальные в упор не видит

Comment: Блин. БЛИН. **БЛИН!!!** Человеку пишешь - что не работает? в ответ "все работает, но в то же время не работает". У вас что-то болит, но вы не хоите сказать, где и как? пойдите выпейте каких-то таблеток, но не скажу, как называются и в какой дозировке.

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, что вы имели в виду, я сделал, как вы предложили, но ничего не изменилось `fread(&stud, sizeof(stud), 1, file);` , `fwrite(stud, sizeof(stud), 1, file);` может дело в указателях? или в sizeof нужно fig написать?